# VBA Canceling SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I've got part of the code:

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

So the user selects where and what name the workbook should have. However, if he clicks "Cancel" or tries to close the window, the workbook still saves under the name "False". How to stop that? The best solution would be to exit sub if the user clicks "Cancel" or closes the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to use `ActiveWorkbook` at all. Instead reference the newly added workbook directly.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveEample()
    Dim NewWb As Workbook
    Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add 'set the new added workbook to a variable so we can access it later

    Dim FileLocation As Variant
    FileLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If Not FileLocation = False Then
        NewWb.SaveAs FileName:=FileLocation 
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim s as Variant
 s = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
 if s =  False then

else
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=s
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

The method returns `false` when the user clicks `Cancel`, so you have to check for this case. Something like this should work for you:

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")  
If fileSaveName <> False Then 
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename := fileSaveName
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Pᴇʜ code I modified my to work like I want to:

```
Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add
genpath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If Not genpath = False Then
NewWb.SaveAs filename:=genpath
Else
NewWb.Close
Exit Sub
End If
```